# Class template appeared in the class member access expression

Tags: c++, class, templates, language-lawyer

Quote from 3.4.5/1 (document version N3797):

> In a class member access expression (5.2.5), if the . or -> token is
>   immediately followed by an identifier followed by a <, the identifier
>   must be looked up to determine whether the < is the beginning of a
>   template argument list (14.2) or a less-than operator. The identifier
>   is first looked up in the class of the object expression. If the
>   identifier is not found, it is then looked up in the context of the
>   entire postfix-expression and **shall name a class template**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

struct A { };

template <typename T> class B{ };


int main(){ A *a = new A(); a->B<int>; }
```

The lookup of `B<int>` in the context of the entire postfix-expression is success. But clang++ returns an error:

```
test.cpp:14:32: error: no member named 'B' in 'A'
```

Please, explain that diagnostic message.

The following is not clear for me: If the indetifier is not found, clang++ returns an error. But the standard said that `If the identifier is not found, it is then looked up in the context of the entire postfix-expression and shall name a class template`.

What is the point of looking up after the identifier is not found in the object expression class scope?

Comment: Explain what? Is there any other interpretation possible to that diagnostic aside from what it says?

Comment: I like the new one better.

Comment: That is indeed much better, and I have no idea what *context of the entire postfix-expression* means.

Comment: @Praetorian I think that the _looked up in the context of the entire posfix expression_ means that the name will be looked up as the name appeared in the expression's scope.

Comment: I wonder if it is for [pathological cases like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfdda21a3f239464) (but I don't quite understand why the second test fails). Note that compilation fails if `base` cannot be found from the definition of the class template. Related defect report: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1111

Comment: @dyp What exactly is pathological in this case? http://ideone.com/58bNvC . The result entirely satisfies to the rule which I cited.

Comment: @dyp Does the example contradict to the 5.2.5/2: `In either case, the id-expression shall name a member of the class or of one of its base classes.`

Comment: @DmitryFucintv With "pathological", I was referring to using `.base<0>` without `template` (using unqualified, non-ADL lookup). The second, disabled line does not compile. IIRC there's some passage that says that the parsing of `<` (as either a less-than or a template parameter list opening bracket) is done via usual lookup from the point of definition; I can't find that passage now, though.

Comment: @dyp Actually, I had not read the sec. 14.2/5 which specified that `the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword template.
Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template` at the time I  commented. But my question is not about it. It is about what does `If the identifier is not found, it is then looked up in the context of the entire postfix-expression and shall name a class template.` mean? In what cases this rule applies?

Comment: It applies, as far as I can tell, in the example I've given. Note that `t` is dependent on a template parameter, so name lookup at the point of definition cannot find `base` as a member (injected-class-name) of `T`. This name `base<0>` is found via unqualified lookup from/in the context of the expression `t.base<0>`

Comment: @dyp If the rule mean exactly what you say (If I had understood you correctly, this rule applied only for names depends on template parameter), it is very ambiguously said in the Standard.

Comment: I'm not sure if it *only* applies to dependent names. I even doubt that this is the original intent of the rule. But it seems to apply in this context. As I said, maybe the discussion of CWG1111 can shed some light on this paragraph in the Standard.

Comment: @dyp I've added an answer. It is my currently understanding if the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your construct is banned by §5.2.5[expr.ref]/p2, addressing class member access expressions:

> In either case, the *id-expression* shall name a member of the class or of one of its base classes.

---

> If the identifier is not found, it is then looked up in the context of the entire postfix-expression and shall name a class template.

<s>I believe that this lookup rule is for finding base classes that are templates. A lookup "in the class of the object expression" would find class members, but won't find the base classes themselves.</s> This doesn't seem right as base class names are injected into derived classes as well (see example in §11.1 [class.access.spec]/p5).

---

Edit: Well, here's a pretty contrived example that appears to depend on this rule:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class A {
public:
  void foo() { cout << "A::foo()" << endl; }
};

template <class E>
using base = A<E>;

int main() {
  A<int>* bp = new A<int>();
  bp->base<int>::foo(); 
}
```

Looking up for `base` in `A` won't find it, so you need to look up in the context of the expression as well to determine if `<` is less-than or starting a template argument list. However this clause has a pretty long history (predating template aliases) so there must be another use case that I'm missing...

Comment: This does not explain the meaning of **If the identifier is not found, it is then looked up in the context of the entire postfix-expression and shall name a class template.** from 3.4.5/1.

Comment: @RSahu Can you explain what does it mean?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv, I'm racking my brains to understand that sentence but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @RSahu At the time I posted this, the question hasn't been edited.

Comment: Yeah! It really works :). But I don't understanding what exactly template <class E> using base = A<E>; mean? Can you get a reference to the Standard described that construction?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv It's an alias template, clause 14.5.7.

Comment: Better late than never: could [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f89261ae61e158f7) be the missing use case you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

A simple example where the meaning of **If the identifier is not found, it is then looked up in the context of the entire postfix-expression and shall name a class template** becomes clear.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> struct B
{
   T data;
};

struct A : B<int>
{
   float data;
};

int main()
{
   A *a = new A();
   a->data = 25.3;
   a->B<int>::data = 10; // Accessing the data from the base class, B<int>
                         // The name B is looked up from the context of the
                         // expression. B<int> is a base class. So, the
                         // expression is a way to get to the members of
                         // B<int>

   a->B<float>::data = 10.1; // Not OK since B<float> is not a base class of A

   std::cout << a->data << std::endl;
   std::cout << a->B<int>::data << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: So in what exactly cases an identifier is looked up in the context of the entire postfix-expresion?

Comment: Hmm, are the `B`s looked up from the context of the expression, though? I think they are found as injected-class-names. If you put the base class in a separate namespace, it can still be [found](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4d497d1540c6f8c).

Comment: @T.C. It seems you are right. It is because clause 10.2.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the sense of this rule is to lookup an alias for name which denotes the class member. The following simple example:

```
#include<iostream>

struct A
{
    int a;
    A(){ a = 5; }
};

typedef A B;

int main()
{
    A *a = new A();
    std::cout << a->B::a; //Usual unqualified name lookup applied
}
```

Comment: This identifier `B` is not followed by a `<`.

Comment: Actually, this refers to the rule 3.4.5/3. But I think that the sense is the same as R Sahu specified in his answer.